# Where do I put the api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll file?

Tags: c++, system-error

So, while trying to run a program, I got the error

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I need it for an upcoming project for school, and I can't download the C++ redistributable or whatever that would reinstall it, because it's a school laptop and I don't have administrator access. I managed to get the actual file itself, but I don't know where to put it. Can someone help?

Comment: You should be able to put it in the same directory as the executable, but beware. Those DLLs are usually very tightly integrated, and you may find yourself in a long chain of DLL hunting. And even then having the missing DLLs does not mean that some other functionality hasn't changed behind the scenes, such as functions missing in older versions of DLLs that were not missing, functions with a different prototypes or functions with radically different behaviour. See is you can statically link your program instead with the /MT option.

Comment: @user4581301 /MT? What's that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: @user4581301 I'm confused on what that's saying. How would I do that?

Comment: I don't think I can explain it any better than what's written under the "To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment" section.

Comment: @user4581301 alright. well thanks, anyway, for helping.

Comment: That one DLL is not enough, there is a bunch of them required once your program uses the CRT. There is an official way to put together what they call a "local deployment" set of DLLs, but you need to have the Windows 10 SDK installed (if you don't have it already). See [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) for more details, in particular the `updated September 11, 2015` part.

Answer (score -1):

The correct location for this file is  in C/Windows/system32